# Almost empty plan cache

Tags: sql-server, performance

I am experiencing a strange situation - my plan cache is almost empty. I use the following query to see what's inside:

```
SELECT dec.plan_handle,qs.sql_handle, dec.usecounts, dec.refcounts, dec.objtype
  , dec.cacheobjtype, des.dbid, des.text,deq.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS dec
join sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs on dec.plan_handle=qs.plan_handle
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(dec.plan_handle) AS des
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(dec.plan_handle) AS deq
WHERE cacheobjtype = N'Compiled Plan'
AND objtype IN (N'Adhoc', N'Prepared')
```

One moment it shows me 82 rows, the next one 50, then 40 then 55 and so on while an hour before I couldn't reach the end of the plan cache issuing the same command. The point is that SQL Server keeps the plan cache very-very small.
The main reason of my investigation is high CPU compared to our baselines without any high loads, under normal during-the day workload - constantly 65-80%

Perfmon counters show low values for Plan Cache Hit Ratio - around 30-50%, high compilations - 400 out of 2000 batch requests per second and high CPU - 73 avg. What could cause this behaviour?

The main purpose of the question is to learn the possible reasons for an empty plan cache.

Memory is OK - min: 0 max: 245000.

I also didn't notice any signs of memory pressure - PLE, lazy writes, free list stalls disk activity were just ok, logs did not tell me a thing.
 I came here for possible causes of this so I could proceed with investigation.

EDIT: I have also considered this thread:

[SQL Server 2008 plan cache is almost always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760648/sql-server-2008-plan-cache-is-almost-always-empty)

But none of the recommendations/possible reasons are relevant.

Comment: You should ask this on dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

> The main purpose of the question is to learn the possible reasons for an empty plan cache.

If it is to learn,the answer from Martin Smith,in [the thread you referred will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36763573/2975396)

If you want to know in particular,why plan is getting emptied,i recommend using extended events and try below extended event

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. I will definitely consider you recomendation. Yet, are there any other methods - profiler, for example? I've got SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I just checked Profiler, idont see any event in profiler

Comment: Leave aside Martin article for a while.Suppose query is so bad that no plan is cache.Is this possible ?Something in this line ?

Comment: i assume you are  asking,if the query is bad,will it be cached.? Query will be cached only when SQL seems it as fit,I remember reading the exact phrase that is used to describe this,but i can't recall now.Read this for more  info:http://stackoverflow.com/a/3628964/2975396 @KumarHarsh

Comment: Thanks. i meant exactly same.

Comment: @TheGameiswar, I've also posted the question on sqlservercentral and I got a supposition. Could that be true?
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1873955/Almost-empty-plan-cache?Update=1#bm1874135

Comment: try leaving memory as per best practices and i am not 100% sure,if plan cache is affected first(i think buffer pool will be affected)